# Record Equals or GetHashCode throws NullReferenceException

Tags: f#, nullreferenceexception, .net-4.5

I have a number of records that look like this:

```
[<DataContract>]
type Rec1 = {
    [<DataMember>] mutable field1 : int;
    [<DataMember>] mutable field2 : string;
}

[<DataContact>]
type Rec2 = { 
    [<DataMember>] mutable field3 : Rec1;
    [<DataMember>] mutable field4 : int;
}
```

I use `DataContactJsonSerializer` to deserialize JSON into this structure. This is a valid JSON value:

```
{ "field3": null, "field4": 1 }
```

Which means at runtime, `field3` is `null/Unchecked.defaultOf<_>`. In Visual Studio 2010, this test works fine:

```
(deserialize<Rec2> "{ field3: null, field4: 1 }") = { field3 = Unchecked.defaultOf<_>; field4 = 1 } //true
```

In Visual Studio 2013, the same code throws a `NullReferenceException`:

```
at Rec2.Equals(Rec2 obj)
```

Peeking at the code in ILSpy, I see this is generated:

```
if(this != null)
{
    return obj != null && this.field3.Equals(obj.field3) && this.field4.Equals(obj.field4);
}
return obj == null;
```

So the issue is the compiler assumes that `field3` is never null which isn't the case since `DataContractJsonSerializer` sets the value to `null`. I've tried applying the `AllowNullLiteral`attribute to `Rec1` but F# records aren't allowed to have that attribute applied to them. How can I either tell the compiler that the fields can be `null` or re-structure my types to allow this to work?

Comment: This is somewhat to be expected when using `Unchecked`. If a missing value is valid, you should probably use `option<Rec1>` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

F# is generating the types assuming it will only ever be used from F# where `null` isn't possible.  Because `[<AllowNullLiteral>]` isn't allowed on that element I don't think there is a way to control code gen such that it will account for this possibility.  I can think of 2 approaches to fixing this

1. Implement custom equality on the `Rec2` instead of the default structural equality.  This means you have to write the equality method yourself which is unfortunate but it should allow you to account for the possibility of `null`
2. Change the code to generate `struct` instances instead of `class`.  This eliminates the possibility of `null` in any CLR use case.  This will require you to move from a record definition to a full type though

Comment: Overriding Equal and GetHashCode still leaves a null value in field3. Whenever your code accesses field3, you will get the `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem on a project. In my opinion, it is a bug in the generated code for `Equal` and `GetHashCode`.

A workaround for me was to replace the null values immediately after deserialization. See the `removeNulls` function that I have added to your sample code:

```
[<DataContract>]
type Rec1 =
    {
        [<DataMember>] mutable field1 : int
        [<DataMember>] mutable field2 : string
    }
    static member empty = { field1 = 0; field2 = String.Empty }

[<DataContract>]
type Rec2 =
    { 
        [<DataMember>] mutable field3 : Rec1;
        [<DataMember>] mutable field4 : int;
    }
    static member removeNulls (rec2 : Rec2) =
        { rec2 with
            field3 = if Object.ReferenceEquals(rec2.field3, null)
                         then Rec1.empty
                         else rec2.field3
        }

      :
      :         

let rec2 = deserialize<Rec2> json
let rec2' = Rec2.removeNulls rec2
```

This solves the problem throughout your use of the Rec2 instance -- not just when the framework happens to call `Equal` or `GetHashCode`. Otherwise, you will have to check that `field3` is not null whenever you access it in your code too.

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to be that you think `null` is a valid value of the `Rec1` type but it isn't. That value is not valid there so you are feeding garbage data into F# code.

You'll get similar behaviour if you feed `null` into any code where it is not expected. For example:

```
2::1::Unchecked.defaultof<_>
```

prints `[2]` which is just nonsense. Garbage in, garbage out...